# Passing additional variable to partial using @each in blade

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5

From the documentation, only 4 parameters can be passed to `@each`. I don't think that using `@include` will help. Code is below

```
@each('partials.nav.categories', $groupCategories, 'parent')
```

I need to send through an additional variable for use in the partial `partials.nav.categories`. This variable is not contained within the `$groupCategories` array.

Is there any way to send this additional variable through or do I have to append it to each item in the `partials.nav.categories` array?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to use the variables defined in that blade.

Comment: thats' the case, it cannot trace it. Simply undefined

Comment: Try passing all variables as an array. Ex: `@each('partials.nav.categories', [$groupCategories,$moreVariable], 'parent')`

Comment: where can I find the docs about it

Comment: Can you share the portion of your code where you want to pass that _additional variable_ to your view?

Comment: it is plain variable only.. The variable should be expose down to the `@each` level

Comment: As of Laravel 5.2 it's just not possible. Why don't you just use the `@foreach` and `@include` directives instead? They'll give all you the flexibility you need while still maintaining readability.

Comment: Its not very elegant but you can pass any data you need via the session and use the session()->get() helper within the partial.

Answer (score 1):

You can share variable from your controller 
`view()->share('key', 'value');`
That's value will be available across all of your views.

Or, you can create view composers exactly for this view.

```
public function yourmethod()
{
   view()->composer('partials.nav.categories', function($view) {
      $view->with('var', 'value');
   });

   return view('path.to.view', ['groupCategories' => $categories]);
}
```

And `$var` will be available only in `partials.nav.categories` view.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. The only problem is how do I pass additional variable trough `@each` blade.

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul through each directive it's impossible

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. Append data to  $groupCategories is the right way. As per documentation, The fourth param is what will be displayed if the $groupCategories is empty. You can either pass a view template, which will be shown only once, or any text prepended with raw| will be displayed as is.

General format:

```
@each('viewfile-to-render', $data, 'variablename','optional-empty-viewfile')
```

The **first** argument is the template to render. This will usually be a partial, like your nameofyourblade.blade.php.

The **second** one is the iterable dataset, in your case $groupCategories.

The **Third** is the variable name the elements will use when being iterated upon. For example, in foreach ($data as $element), this argument would be element (without the $).

The **fourth** argument is an optional one – it’s the name of the template file which should be rendered when the second argument ($data) is empty, i.e. has nothing to iterate over. If we apply all this to our case, we can replace this entire block:

```
@if (count($groupCategories) > 0)
    <ul>
    @foreach ($groupCategories as $parent)
        @include('partials.nav.categories', $parent)
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@else
    @include('partials.group-none')
@endif
```

with

```
@each('partials.nav.categories', $groupCategories, 'parent', 'partials.group-none')
```

Comment: ok thanks for enlightment. But I need extra data to be passed down to the iteration

Comment: If `$groupCategories` is a proper collection, you can use `$groupCategories->isEmpty()` instead of the `count()` check.

Comment: There is no access to the collection within the partial. Only the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to pass to the partial instance, the variables that change on each use of the partial.

The code inside the partial itself can access anything that is in scope of the parent.

So, if for instance, the main view can use $user, so can the partial - on the understanding that it will be the same value on each inclusion of the partial.

Not sure if this helps since you don't say if the additional parameter needs to be different for each inclusion of the partial.

Comment: as you can see, I have  `$groupCategories` variable looped in `partials.nav.categories` but I also have another variable called `$mainCategory` to used within the `@each`. It is used to check whether every item in the loop match or not match to the `$mainCategory`

Comment: @Snapey The question is related to `@each`, that doesn't propagates the variables as `@include` does. In a subview called using `@each` there is no access.